# How to upload and download a file using Load Runner script?

Tags: loadrunner

Need help to create a scenario for file upload and download. Would like to track the duration of upload and download of files.

Comment: Could you please provide more details on what exactly you are trying to do. What protocol? Which LR version? What is the scenario you are trying to reproduce. Your current question is too generic to provide a valid answer.

Comment: Your upload/download mechanism may involve a second communication type, such as FTP, SFTP, NFS, SMB, etc...  You need to know precisely the architectural mechanism used for upload/download before you can set a path for implementation in development